# Moveable QGraphicsItem parent but not child QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, pyside

When creating a `QGraphicsItem` via QT and Pyside, you can set it's parent using `childItem.setParentItem(parentItem)`.  If the `ItemIsMoveable` flag is set on the parent, dragging the parent will translate the parent and all of it's children.

In my use case, I want to be able to drag the parent and child when dragging from anywhere inside the parent but not also inside the child.  I would like to have a different action when clicking and dragging in the child.  For example, if making a node-graph editor, being able to drag a node and it's connection points, but when dragging from a connection point outwards, creating a graph edge.

Can this be accomplished using the built in QT flags, or is it necessary to overload the mouse move event for the parent item?  I had initially gone down the overloading route, but felt like I might be fighting something already built in.

Comment: I think I may not have searched well enough.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273785/only-move-qgraphicsitem-when-mouse-in-specific-region?rq=1) is nearly identical.  I'm going to try and implement and if it looks good, I'll answer this question or maybe just close it based on what I find.  I wouldn't mind a discussion on the most "QT" way of doing it, but this may be a duplicate.

Comment: just provide empty implementation of `mousePressEvent` (possibly also other mouse events) for the child. Then child will steal all mouse events in his range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marek R's answer is the cleanest I've found.  Simply implement the `mousePressEvent` in the child to prevent it from causing moveable behavior of the parent:

```
class Child(QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
  def __init__(self, name):
    super(Child, self).__init__()

  def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    pass
```